# Angular 7 + Kendo UI Treeview

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, rxjs, angular7

### I want to create dynamic TreeView with Kendo UI for Angular, the structure which i want is like below:

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
  Folder 2.1
  Folder 2.2
  Test Case 2.1
  Test Case 2.2
      Test Step 2.2.1
      Test Step 2.2.2
  Test Case 2.3
Folder 3
  Test Case 3.1 
      Test Step 3.1.1
      Test Step 3.1.2
```

---

```
selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-treeview
        [nodes]="varg | async"
        [textField]="['name']"

        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
        [children]="getChildren"
        >
    </kendo-treeview>
```

### `

```
public varg: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private treeserviceService:  TreeserviceService) {}  

  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.varg = this.treeserviceService.getTestFolders()  
    ;
  } 
  public hasChildren = (item: any) => 'name' in item; 

  public getChildren = (item: any) => 
  this.treeserviceService.getAllFolderAndTestCases(item.noderef);
```

But my problem is that when I click for example in Folder 2 I can't get Folder and Test Cases, because it is showing error

Comment: What error do you get? Can you provide us a running [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will help us to help you.

Comment: @Philipp this is link to see picture with example and error which is returned back

[link](https://pasteboard.co/HMbZyEv.png)

Comment: What is the returned value & type of `this.treeserviceService.getAllFolderAndTestCases`?

Comment: I would need to return data from Observables from two different functions like below:

 public getSubFolders(noderef: number): any {
    return this.fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/testfolders/${noderef}/testfolders`);
  }

  public getTestCases(noderef: number): any {
    return this.fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/testfolders/${noderef}/testcases`);
  }

 private fetch(url: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response));
  }

Comment: Me too have exactly the same problem? Does anyone know the fix? It would be really helpful